# Why $1/(1-x) \neq 1/(-x+1)$ in long division for generating functions?

Tags: power-series, generating-functions

If you do a long division of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{-x+1}$ to obtain a formal series of generating functions, you'll get different results:

$$
\frac{1}{1-x} = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + ...
$$
$$
\frac{1}{-x+1} = -\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{x^3}-...
$$

But we expect in both cases to get $g(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 +...$

I do know that one can show that generating functions, corresponding to $\frac{1}{1-x}$ and $\frac{1}{-x+1}$ are the same by considering $(1-x)g(x) = (-x+1)g(x) = 1$ identity, but it is quite disturbing for me that long polynomial division, which I used to trust, does not work.
Moreover, the former fraction, $\frac{1}{-x+1}$ feels more natural during long division process, because it has the highest term going first.

So, what is the reason of why I get different results? (for example, maybe summation operation is not commutative in this kind of things so we have $(1-x) \neq (-x+1)$)

Comment: The first series converges for $|x|<1$ and the second converges for $|x|>1$.

Comment: Can you edit the question to show us just what "long polynomial division" you used to get the second expression. That expression is formally correct, but it's not a power series. I suspect there's nothing "polynomial" in your process.

Comment: One does not use polynomial  long division to obtain the generating function, but division by `increasing powers`. So one begins dividing $1$ by the *lowest degree* terms in the divisor, i.e. $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the ring of formal power series, $x$ is "smaller" than $1$, not larger. The most significant (i.e. "highest") term of $1-x$ is $1$, not $-x$.

The *valuation* in the ring of formal power series is the opposite of the one you're used to in terms of polynomial degree.

Answer (score 1):

The first series holds when
$|x| < 1$.
The second holds when
$|x| > 1$.

The concept behind this
is analytic continuation.

Comment: Another way of stating this: 1st series converges if $\,x^n \to 0\,$ and 2nd series converges if $\,\frac1x^n \to 0.\,$

Answer (score 1):

Long division does not give an infinite series. It gives a finite series plus a remainder (and that leads to an infinite series *if* the remainder tends to $0$).

If you write down finitely many terms plus the remainder it turns out they're the same. (For the first series the remainder tends to $0$ if $|t|<1$, while for the second the remainder tends to $0$ if $|t|>1$..)